# Sessão não funciona como esperado em requisição Ajax e PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, post

Bom eu tenho uma página principal **index.php** onde a pessoa executa uma ação e realiza uma requisição **POST com Ajax**. Neste arquivo principal eu crio uma sessão com alguns dados que eu quero manter mais seguros e não ficarem visíveis e outros para confirmações.

**Exemplo: index.php**

```
<?php
// exemplo da sessão
$_SESSION['EXAMPLE'] = [
    'token' => '123456abcExample',// SEMPRE UM NOVO E ÚNICO TOKEN É GERADO AO CARREGAR A PÁGINA index.php
    'other' => 'stringEtc'
];
?>
...
<script>
// exemplo da requisição ajax - no mesmo site
// página "http://example.com/url/index.php" e a outra "http://example.com/url/request.php"

$.post('http://example.com/url/request.php', {
    'example' => 'string',
    'token' => $_SESSION['EXAMPLE']['token']
}, function (response) {
    // code
}, 'json');
</script>
```

Tem uma *segunda página* **request.php**, para onde mando a requisição **ajax** com retorno JSON. Nessa *segunda página* eu faço uma verificação se o **token** da *sessão* é o mesmo que foi passado para a requisição *AJAX*, e apenas sendo o mesmo para continuar o código.

**Exemplo: request.php**

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['EXAMPLE']['token'] == $_POST['token']) {...}
```

Porém, na *segunda página* o **token da sessão** chega diferente do que era antes. Vamos dizer que na página principal *"index.php"* o token criado na sessão fosse **"12345abcExampleToken"**, também é passado pro *data* do AJAX  igualmente, porém na segunda página ele chega como **"789452hjkhToken"**, ou seja outro totalmente diferente, como se a *index.php* tivesse sido iniciada de novo e criado um novo token.

Bom, eu gostaria de saber por que isto pode está acontecendo. E se houver uma solução mais segura ("se esta maneira que estou utilizando é realmente segura"), por favor poderia me compartilhar?

> **Nota - Edição:** O token é gerado através de uma função de *Classe Estática*, achei bom informar, em caso de isto ter algo haver!

```
class Example
{
    public static function getToken(): string
    {
        return 'createToken';
    }
}
```

e eu uso assim na sessão:

```
$_SESSION['EXAMPLE'] = [
    'token' => Example::getToken(),
    'other' => 'stringEtc'
];
```

Comment: no $.post, o 'token' está sendo enviado corretamente mas no request.php na SESSION está incorreto?

Comment: @Everson sim, está chegando diferente. Eu fiz um "echo" pra exibir a session assim que criada e vejo também o do $.post, e claro da request.php também. Mas nela chega diferente

Comment: Uma das formas de tentar perceber onde está o problema é verificar o post enviado através do inspecionar no separador de rede, olhando para os dados do post. Pode depois fazer um echo no php mal o token é gerado, para que possa comparar os dois

Comment: @Isac Como eu posso fazer isso? "inspecionar no separador de rede"

Comment: Abra o inspecionar fazendo `botão direito` seguido de `Inspecionar`. Regra geral isso corresponde ao `F12` na maior parte dos navegadores. Nessa janela de inspeção o separador de Rede(Network) costuma ser o 3º no Chrome, e apresenta todos os pedidos que foram feitos e mostra os dados enviados/recebidos. Basta clicar em qualquer um para ver a informação especifica desse pedido.

Comment: Eu fiz o teste, e troquei o "token" por "data/hora" e o do "request.php" fica com 2, 3 segundos a mais. Exemplo: `index.php` **2017-08-18 23:22:35** --- `request.php` **2017-08-18 23:22:37**. Isso acontece independente se eu fiz a requisição ou não, pois eu esperei alguns segundos pra fazer a requisição e ver se era nessa hora, mas continuou 2 á 3 segundos de diferença

Comment: Seria melhor colocar o código certo pra analise. Porque para mim isso parece que como você estivesse chamando novamente `getToken()` , talvez seja por usar `include`

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza adicionei o código, e realmente eu uso include/require, tem como eu resolver isso?

Comment: Algumas coisas estão sem comentários, pois estou adicionando agora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o que estava causando isto! Eu não sei porque isto acontece, mas era um **elemento HTML** o qual tinha o atributo *style* com o ***background*** vazio da seguinte maneira:

`<section class="..." style="background: url('') center;"></section>`

Talvez seja por ele estar chamando novamente a página

Answer (score 0):

Vamos exemplificar, que esse código seria sua **index.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['TOKEN'] = md5(time()); // Gera o Token e salva na sessão
echo "O TOKEN É: " . $_SESSION['TOKEN']; // imprime a Sessão Token na tela
```

> Aqui seria sua **request.php**, se ela estiver incluindo a
>   **index.php** automaticamente vai gerar outra Token e sobrescrever a **$_SESSION['TOKEN']**

```
include "index.php";
if ($_SESSION['TOKEN'] == $_POST['TOKEN']) {
    // isso daria errado, porque ? porque fez o include da index.php
}
```

Minha recomendação, é você criar um novo arquivo, exemplo: resquest2.php e realizar apenas a verificação dos dados

```
if ($_SESSION['TOKEN'] == $_POST['TOKEN']) {
    // isso daria certo, porque ? porque não fez o include da index.php
}
```

**Abservação:**

> Se você chama o método **getToken()** que esta na classe **Example**
>   em sua **index.php** você não pode chamar esse método novamente em sua
>   **request.php**, pois ele ira sobrescrever o TOKEN anterior.

**Exemplo:**

```
Example::getToken(); // Estaria sobrescrevendo a $_SESSION['TOKEN']
if ($_SESSION['TOKEN'] == $_POST['TOKEN']) {
    // isso daria errado.
}
```

Comment: Realmente faz sentido, mas eu não estou incluindo a `index.php` =/ os includes que estou fazendo no começo tanto da `index.php`, quanto da `request.php`, são de 2 arquivos nos quais eu inicio algumas coisas, como o `session_start`, conexão com banco de dados e a chamada com `autoload` do composer pros namespaces, no qual incluem o Example::getToken(). Então são esses que podem estar fazendo isso? pois eu faço include dele na index.php e na request.php tb, como eu poderia resolver?

Comment: Você só não pode executar o metodo `getToken()` na **request.php**, porque ele cria outra Hash e sobrescreve a anterior.

Comment: Vou colocar na resposta para poder ficar mais clara.

Comment: Bom, eu fiz um teste ao invés de por `getToken`, eu usei o `rand()` do php, na index ele me gerou `28077`, já na request `19593`. Eu uso o `session_start()` com include em ambas, mas a sessão **req_token** é dado valor apenas na index, tem alguma coisa em mente?

Comment: Este é o header da requisição, se de algo servir :) https://prnt.sc/gabw9e

Comment: Vamos conversar no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64093/sessao-nao-funciona-como-esperado-em-requisicao-ajax-e-php)

Comment: Finalmente descobri, muito obrigado pela ajuda :D