# Como confirmar se a requisição foi realizada através do site de forma segura

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, requisição

Bom gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de eu confirmar que a requisição veio realmente do site e não de fora, e também está sendo feita pela página com a ação do usuário.

Tentei fazer uma solução para isso, mas não deu muito certo. Que foi criar uma sessão com token único toda vez q a página é iniciada e ser mandada através de ajax para outra página, porém o token chega diferente. Pergunta: [Sessão não funciona como esperado em requisição Ajax e PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228642/sess%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-funciona-como-esperado-em-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-e-php?noredirect=1#comment468506_228642)

Então gostaria de saber se existi uma maneira de verificar se os dados enviados forem realmente feitos pela página e como posso fazê-lo/aplicá-lo em PHP, Javascript ou jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Olá,

Não é possível criar um sistema que garanta 100% que a requisição foi realizada a partir de uma página do seu site, pois tecnicamente nenhuma requisição é feita "do seu site" enquanto o usuário está navegando, pois todas requisições são feitas pelo navegador (browser), ou seja, pelo cliente. E tudo que vem do cliente é passível de ser manipulável.

A única forma seria se literalmente a requisição fosse feita pelo servidor, ou seja, você fazer uma requisição usando por ex. curl direto do PHP para uma url da sua aplicação, mas entendo que isso foge do propósito do seu questionamento.

> Conclusão: Não é possível ter 100% de garantia de origem de uma
>   requisição HTTP de um cliente que não é controlado por você ou pela
>   sua própria aplicação.

Segue um diagrama ilustrando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Existem dois pontos a serem considerados, uma delas tem solução:

- Quero impedir que **um outro website** envie requisição ao meu site:

  > Um website (`malicioso.com`) está fazendo requisições para `seusite.com`, se aproveitando inclusive das sessões iniciadas pelo usuário em seu site.
- Quero impedir que envie requisições ao meu site estando **fora dele**.

  > Um software que não é um navegador (por exemplo: `curl`) está fazendo requisições para o `seusite.com`, tipicamente de maneira automática e não-humana.

---

O primeiro caso existe um site que executa no lado do cliente tal requisição, por exemplo:

```
malicioso.com:
 <img src="http://seusite.com/deletar_conta.php">
```

Quando acessar a página irá chamar sua página. Isso poderia ser feito com AJAX ou qualquer outro método, desde que executado no lado do cliente, no navegador do usuário que está acessando o `malicioso.com`.

**Soluções:**

Fácies e aplicáveis em uso geral, com baixo impacto para o usuário:

- Adicione o *header* de `X-Frame-Options` para `DENY`

  > Isso irá impedir que outro site faça um `iframe` do seu website.
- Adicione CSRF-Token (usando um CSPRNG) em todos os formulários.

  > O site malicioso não terá acesso ao CSRF-Token, exceto se houver outra vulnerabilidade, tal como XSS.
- Adicione a *flag* de `SameSite` para `strict` no cookie da sessão (não suportado nativamente pelo PHP, mas tem como fazer isso manualmente):

  > A requisição feita para o seu site não terá os cookies, mas isso ainda é um recurso experimental e não suportado em todos os navegador.

Moderado, com baixo impacto para o usuário:

- Envie uma chave pública (caso RSA) ou chave comum (caso HMAC ou AES-GCM) ao usuário e utilize-a para realizar as chamadas via AJAX.

  > A chave estará no corpo da página ou no localStorage e será usado para assinar/encriptar as informações, o site malicioso não terá acesso a essas informações, exceto se houver outra vulnerabilidade.

Difíceis e com alto impacto para o usuário:

- Não use cookies como sessões e nem recicle sessões.

  > Você pode usar por exemplo o websocket, uma vez iniciada a conexão nenhuma outra com mesmo identificador poderá ser aberta. Uma outra opção é usar alguma derivação de chave, dessa forma quando o usuário fizer o login ambas as partes conseguem reconhecer o usuário chave gerada. Ambos casos qualquer nova requisição feita pelo site malicioso não conseguirá aproveitar uma sessão já aberta.

---

O segundo caso é querer impedir que envie requisições fora do meu site, impedir que consigam automatizar ações ou que utilize softwares como cURL para fazer requisições no meu site, como por exemplo:

```
curl -X "POST" -d "CSRF=12345678&CONTA=12345678" -H "Cookie: sessao=ui1j3dasqwe123;" -H "Referer: seusite.com" https://seusite.com/deletar_conta.php
```

Quero ter certeza que o usuário moveu o mouse até o botão e clicou lá, dentro do meu site.

**Soluções:**

- Não há como

**"Pseudo-Soluções":**

Isso não vai corrigir o problema, as requisições ainda podem ser feitas fora do seu site!

- Adicione `Captcha` para evitar requisições não-humanas.

  > Isso irá aumentar o custo para que consiga enviar a requisição fora do website, um *bot* não conseguirá fazer essa requisição de maneira fácil, porém ainda é possível.
  >
  > Normalmente o usuário terá que escrever em texto a mensagem exibida em imagem, isso pode ser inconveniente ao usuário, porém se tem maior certeza de que o usuário realmente é legitimo, afinal foi capaz de escrever o texto correto.
- Adicione um PoW (ex `hashcash`) para evitar automações.

  > Isso é baseado no Bitcoin. O usuário deverá calcular uma hash e isto custará poder computacional, aumentando o custo para que novas requisições sejam feitas.

Comment: `Não recicle sessões`; Isso significa que eu devo criar uma nova sessão a cada requisição do usuário mesmo que ele não tenha fechado a aba/feito logoff?

Comment: @guilherme.oc97 Sim. Você pode utilizar websocket para isso, se a conexão for cortada automaticamente a sessão é encerrada. Ou, você pode utilizar o `sessionStorage` do navegador, que é "zerado" sempre que abre numa nova aba ou atualiza a página, por exemplo, ou seja apenas existe naquela página. Isso é muito diferente dos cookies, que ficam com o mesmo valor "para sempre".